How to format single line "impl A<> ... for B<> ... where ..." to multiple lines
Can I configure the Rust Formatter to split the following
to multiple indentations lines?
Given
/// comment
impl<T> MyTrait<T> for I<T> where T: SomeTrait {}

expected after formatting
/// comment
impl<T>
    MyTrait<T>
for
    I<T> 
where 
    T: SomeTrait
{
}

Formatting the "where" clause with indents seems fine,
but long lines with "impls", generics and "for/where" are
on one line and this is, at least for me, nearly unreadable.

Configuration options are available here: https://rust-lang.github.io/rustfmt A quick glance suggests no

I have read the RustFmt docs, and I have not found a solution. This is why I'm asking. Next time I'll try to be more specific, my fault.
